# Shiny HTML Element and DT::renderDataTable output$

Tags: html, r, class, shiny, dt

My webpage is done in HTML and connected to Shiny via simple output$ matching IDs of HTML Elements.

To represent table data on the webpage the code below works fine:

**server.R**

```
output$InfoTable <- renderTable({...})
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="InfoTable " class="shiny-html-output"></div>
```

**Now my question...**

How does this work for DataTable?

```
output$InfoDataTable <- DT::renderDataTable({...})
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="InfoDataTable" class="???"></div>
```

How does the div look like?
I found datatables, which did not work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Run the app from the console and inspect in browser. This is what came up for me with a `datatable` with default attributes:

```
class="datatables html-widget html-widget-output shiny-bound-output"
```

Comment: thanks Vance, that's what I tried as well and tried again. Unfortunately, this does not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the script:

*'`<script src="datatables-binding-0.5/datatables.js"></script>`'*

and the div class for the renderDataTable is ***datatables html-widget html-widget-output***